# Best option for keeping alive a process in AWS after shuting down SSH?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, ssh

I am deploying a web page with Flask using AWS and EC2. The web works by running a app in python which makes the calculations and sends variables and content to an html and javascript. I run that from SSH and I would like it to keep working when I shut down my computer. I read screen is a good option. Any other recommendation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the quick tests `tmux`, `screen`, `nohup` or `pm2` are commonly used.

However, for proper setup, you would define your own [systemd unit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) files for your flask app. Or alternatively use [Elastic Beanstalk which can host your flask app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) and manage all this for you.